# Update JSON array using SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have JSON like below:

```
{
 "property": {
  "commonProperty": "abc",
  "Items": [
   {
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "a"
   },
   {
    "ID": 2,
    "Name": "a"
   },
   {
    "ID": 3,
    "Name": "b"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

And what I want to achieve is to update Names to "c" where it's currently "a" using SQL Server (so I want to have result like below).

```
{
 "property": {
  "commonProperty": "abc",
  "Items": [
   {
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "c"
   },
   {
    "ID": 2,
    "Name": "c"
   },
   {
    "ID": 3,
    "Name": "b"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

As far as I know I cannot use `JSON_MODIFY` because it does not handles queries inside it's arguments and `OPENJSON` cannot be updated. Is there any method I can use?

EDIT note: added common property above Items.

Comment: Would the "dumb" solution of just replacing `"Name": "a"` with `"Name": "c"` using `REPLACE` work for you? Obviously not in general since there could be any number of objects with a `Name` property, but for specific scenarios you can get away with it (possibly by selecting the array separately first, then replacing it as a whole).

Comment: Unfortunately it's only representation of problem that exists in huge database with way more complex JSONs. Otherwise it would be helpful though so thank you for an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You may try one of the following options:

- Parse the `'$.property.Items'` JSON array as table using `OPENJSON()`, make an update, output the table's content as JSON using `FOR JSON` and modify the original JSON using `JSON_MODIFY()`:
- Build a dynamic statement. You can modify the input JSON using `JSON_MODIFY()` and the appropriate `path`. The `path` needs to be defined as a literal or from SQL Server 2017 as a variable, but using a wildcard is not possible (e.g. the statement `SELECT @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, '$.property.Items[0].Name', N'c')` modifies the first item in the `Items` JSON array).

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
   "property":{
      "commonProperty":"abc",
      "Items":[
         {
            "ID":1,
            "Name":"a"
         },
         {
            "ID":2,
            "Name":"a"
         },
         {
            "ID":3,
            "Name":"b"
         }
      ]
   }
}'
```

Statement (that parses the JSON as a table, modifies the table and outputs the table's content as JSON):

```
SELECT @json = JSON_MODIFY(
   @json,
   '$.property.Items',
   (
   SELECT 
      ID AS 'ID', 
      CASE WHEN Name = N'a' THEN N'c' ELSE Name END AS 'Name'
   FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.property.Items') WITH (ID int, Name nvarchar(50))
   FOR JSON PATH
   )
)
```

Dynamic statement:

```
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
SET @stm = (
   SELECT N'SET @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, ''$.property.Items[' + [key] + N'].Name'', N''c''); '
   FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.property.Items')
   WHERE JSON_VALUE([value], '$.Name') = N'a'
   FOR XML PATH('')
)

PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm, N'@json nvarchar(max) OUTPUT', @json OUTPUT
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. First option worked for me, I didn't have time to test the second one yet. The only problem is that if there is additional common property on "property" level (edited initial question) - it's being lost with the first option. I tried few changes but these did not work for me. How should the query be modified to preserve it?

Comment: @TajniakOsz Just change the `JSON_MODIFY()` path expression and remove `PATH('')`. The answer is updated. Thanks.